# JSF - UIInput component with no input sets String Property to empty string

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now. I found a earlier post where BalusC gave advice on creating your own converter called "EmptyToNullConverter" for JSF version 1.2
or specifying a context parameter in JSF 2.0

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

None of these options has worked for me. Has it worked for other people.

Doing some investigation of my own I ended up stepping through the UIInput source. I can see the value is null until it is passed to the ValueExpression. Unfortunately I do not have the source for that so I could not drill down further. I'm assuming it is here where it ends up instantiating a new String Type and rather passing that to the model property?

My environment is as follows

- running Mojarra RI using the jsf-api-2.0.3 and jsf-impl-2.0.3 jars
- also using richfaces 3.3.3, so I had to disable the viewhandler for jsf2. Still using facelets jar as a result
- All this is running on Tomcat 6

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the type of the model property? String or Integer/Long/Number?

Comment: Sorry for repeating myself here but by accident I hit the enter key. Wanted to add that with regards to the answer posted below. I wanted to create wrappers but the model objects are generated from a wsdl file. It seems so weird that you can not configure a framework to allow null entries?

Comment: That's the nature of HTTP. Input fields get always submitted as request parameter name-value pair, regardless of whether the value is filled in or not. In Servlet API, only when the request parameter name is absent, its value will be `null`. You can certainly configure a framework to make empty submitted values `null` instead. You have even mentioned two solutions, one for JSF 2.0 only and other for JSF 1.2 or newer. That they do not work for you doesn't mean that a framework doesn't provide it. Your problem lies likely in RichFaces, but since I don't use it, I can't go in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I know we had this problem using Richfaces and Sun's default JSF implementation 1.2.
One way to work around the problem is using your own custom converters for whatever type you need that convert empty values (0, "") to nulls.

Other way is doing the conversion inside your backingbean:

```
MyBackingBean {

String myValue;

public void setMyValue(String v) {
  if (v==null || v.trim().length==0) {
    myValue==null;
  } else {
    myValue=v;
  }
}

public String getMyValue() {
  return myValue;
}

}
```