# Richfaces: Value is updated when sorting column

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

```
<rich:column sortBy="#{entity.double_amt}" filterBy="#{entity.double_amt}" >
    <h:inputText value="#{entity.double_amt}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="entityTable" ajaxSingle="true" />
</rich:column>
```

I have a column inside a **rich:dataTable**, where user will be able to input Amount and filter/sort.

If user haven't inputted **double_amt**, it will be blank.
However, if I don't input anything, and click on the column header to sort the table (or type anything for filter), **double_amt** will be defaulted with **0.0**. Worse, if I have multiple records on this table, one random **double_amt** from **another row** is inserted in the empty row (instead of **0.0**).

When I click on the column header, **setDouble_amt(Double double_amt)** is called, and **double_amt** here is **0.0**, or the value from another record.

Am I missing anything here? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be similar to this problem described here:

[JSF - UIInput component with no input sets String Property to empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346733/jsf-uiinput-component-with-no-input-sets-string-property-to-empty-string)

In my problem, however, I need to know if user has inputted **0.0** or haven't input anything at all. Either way, the setter is passed **0.0**.

I manage to solve the problem by changing the getter/setter to **String** (**getDoubleAmt()** and **setDoubleAmt(String doubleAmt)**), and check for empty String inputted as in the link provided. If it is not empty, I will **parse the double** to the original field (**double_amt**).

Hope this helps someone facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would start setting the "id" property in all of the elements (specially in a4j:support, I do not think that this solves your problem, but I had bad experiences wit this in the past).

Comment: All due respect, but this is not an answer, this is a comment. If you earn a minimum of 50 reputation by posting true answers, then you can post comments on someone else's questions. I suggest to delete this non-answer and wait until you've at least 50 rep.